# How to convert csv to RDD and use RDD in pyspark for some detection?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, rdd

I'm currently working on a research of heart disease detection and want to use spark to process big data as it is a part of a solution of my work. But i'm having difficulty in using spark with python because i cannot grasp how to use spark. Converting csv file to RDD and then i don't understand how to work with RDD to implement classification algorithms like knn, logistic Regression etc. 
So i would really appreciate it if anyone can help me in anyway.

I have tried to understand pyspark on internet but there are very few codes available and some which are available are too easy or too hard to understand. I cannot find any proper example of classification on pyspark.

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

To read the csv into a dataframe you can just call `spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv('path/to/csv')`.

The dataframe will contain the columns and rows of your csv, and you can convert it into a RDD of rows with `df.rdd`.